# isc-dhcp-server が時々起動しない

Tags: network, raspberry-pi

raspberry pi に isc-dhcp-server を入れてルータとして運用していますが、最近起動しない現象が不定期的に発生しています。起動しない場合は以下のようなメッセージがログに残ります。

```
$ sudo dhcpd -t
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
�`:2218: REQUIRE('M')))))) failed.
Aborted
```

`�:2218: REQUIRE('M')))))) failed.` の部分はその時々で異なるメッセージになります。（systemctlから起動する場合も同じです。）
この原因と解決方法がわかる方はいらっしゃるでしょうか？

設定ファイルは以下のとおりです。

```
$ cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.3.10 192.168.3.20;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.3.255;
  option routers 192.168.3.1;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

```
$ cat /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
INTERFACES='wlan0'
```

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

追記：
エラーログのAbotedの上の行が以下の様になるときもあります。
`�:2218: REQUIRE(((task) != ((void *)0) && (task)->magic == (('A') << 24 | ('t') << 16 | ('s') << 8 | ('t')))) failed.`

Comment: Twitter より、何か勝手に直ってしまったという情報が流れてきたので、[念のためこちらにも貼って](https://twitter.com/koki_h/status/1148455248983236608)おきます。もし質問者さんの都合が悪かった場合は、コメントくださればこのコメントは削除します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

その後、別のSDカードに同じセットアップを行って試してみたところ症状が消えました。その後再発することもないため、SDカードが原因で設定の読み出しが失敗していたことが原因であると考えることにしました。

設定ファイルをviやlessで表示した場合は特に問題なく見えたのですが、見えないゴミのようなデータが入ってしまうことがあったのかもしれません。